# How / when does neurogenesis occur while learning?

Tags: neuroscience, learning

I've heard that learning to Juggle (new things) helps increase neurogenesis. So, what does it depend on?

- Does it have to be a **physical skill** only?
- Or can I study / **read** about Economics(which is new to me) for that?
- Should I have new **emotional** experiences like death in family, first time love etc.?

Also, when we try memorize something, say a poem, **how is it decided that this has to be stored in the existing neurons or in the new neurons**.

I'm aware that while connecting the dots, new connections are formed.

Comment: because it involves a cognitive component (learning) this is an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

It has been discovered that neurogenesis takes place only on the hippocampus.

Quoting [Leonard E. White](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/~242):

> We now agree that the production of new 
>   neurons in the human brain is really 
>   limited to a special set of stem cells 
>   that seem to sit in the basal region of 
>   dentate gyrus of the hippocampus. 
>   So in this subgranular zone, we have a 
>   population of neural stem cells that can 
>   differentiate into interneurons that are 
>   found in the granule cell layer of the 
>   hippocampus.

Also as you said, this production could be modulated through some interventions (e.g. learning)

> This genesis of new 
>   neurons in the hippocampus can be 
>   modulated. 
>   By all kinds of different interventions 
>   including pharmacological agents such as 
>   antidepressant medications. 
>   As well as physical interventions, such 
>   as exercise.

Also, this has been mentioned in this ted talk:

https://www.ted.com/talks/sandrine_thuret_you_can_grow_new_brain_cells_here_s_how

In summary, the following activities impact **positively** on neurogenesis:

- Learning
- Sex
- Running
- Good diet

While these ones impact **negatively**:

- Stress
- Bad sleep
- Ageing

pd: Concerning how memory works, my knowledge there is limited.

Comment: I appreciate that you've presented the things which impact. But I was expecting a few behind the scenes.